# Running a compiled program 20 times and summarizing the result

Tags: bash, unix

I have a compiled program

and run it with the command:

```
 /mnt/c/Users/adan/Documents/cht/cache_adapter/cmake-build-debug/cache_adapter -ds 1 map plain
```

the output is: a number

**My goal**:
To run it 20 times and summarize all the outputs.

I wrote this script but it is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
run_iterations="$1"
if [ "$run_iterations" == "" ]; then
    run_iterations=1
fi
# Write the data structures you would like to run. The options: "map" "unordered_map" "gcc"
 dataStructures="$2"
 #if  [("$dataStructures" != "map") || ("$dataStructures" != "gcc") ||( "$mode" != "unordered_map")];then 
 #  echo wrong ds!
 #  exit 1
  #fi

mode="$3"
 #if  ["$mode" != "plain" || "$mode" != "gcc" || "$mode" != "unordered_map"];then 
 #  echo wrong mode!
 #  exit 1
  #fi
exec_name="release"
size=1000000
numOfElem=500000
workSetSize=250
iterations=10000
numOfWorkSets=10
total_time=0 

for ((i=0; i<1; i++ )); do
run_time= ` /mnt/c/Users/adan/Documents/cht/cache_adapter/cmake-build-debug/cache_adapter -ds 1 map plain|cut -f 5`
echo $run_time
((total_time = total_time +runtime))  
done 

echo $total_time
```

But it's not working and keep returning always 0.

Would appreciate some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: `((total_time = total_time +run_time))` you are missing an underscore

Comment: What is `echo $run_time` showing? Perhaps replace `run_time=$(/mnt/c/Users/adan/Documents/cht/cache_adapter/cmake-build-debug/cache_adapter -ds 1 map plain|cut -f 5)` with `runtime=$RANDOM` and start debugging from there.

Comment: You might notice the missing underscore @MarkSetchell found and the incorrect space after `run_time=`.